# Problems installing Ubuntu 64 bit dual boot with windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot

I have a brand new system using Gigabyte B85M-D3H motherboard, 8 Gigs 1600Mhz Memory, Intel i3-4330 3.5 GHz processor, ADATA 128 GiG SSD, WD15EARS Hard Drive. I partioned the SSD into 90 Gig and 30 Gig partitions, hoping to create a dual-boot Windows 8.1 Pro and Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit systems. When I first downloaded an Ubuntu .iso, I was looking for a 64 bit Intel version and chose i386 instead of AMD.

The 1st install went seamlessly but I realized that Ubuntu was only 32 bit. I followed online discussions to remove Ubuntu, Create a Bootable CD for Ubuntu 64 bit and followed the same steps as I did the 1st time. This time however, Ubuntu 64 did not recognize the Windows 8.1 install and wanted to overwrite the 90Gig partition. I directed it to install to the WD15EARS which was previously partitioned into 2 750Gig volumes. When I was finished, the system booted into Ubuntu, ignoring Windows 8.1. I essentially ended up with 2 independent OS systems changeable through the bios. When I went into Window 8.1 and looked at the drives, a 350Mb chunk of Ubuntu thinks its a part of the SSD ADATA drive. In addition it says the WD15EARS drive is locked and inaccessible. There was some grub message error saying drive locked but I am new to linix and do not know command line instructions

Answer (score 0):

while rebooting press F2. Then see if UEFI is enabled. Ubuntu does not install on your system with that enabled. Whilst Windows-8 requires UEFI.